# Как реализовать множественное наследование интерфейсов в typescript

Tags: c#, typescript, интерфейс

Есть 2 интерфейста с одинаковыми именами методов и разными сигнатурами. И есть 1 класс, который реализует оба интерфейса. В c# к примеру пишут так `IInterface.Method()` `IInterface2.Method()`. Как сделать в typescript такое?

Answer (score 0):

А зачем? Если это два интерфейса, так назови их методы по разному.
В своё время предлагались варианты явного указания сигнатуры, но не знаю - вошли ли они в релиз или так и остались предложениями. Попробуй.

```
interface A {
    foo(a:string):void
}

interface B {
    foo(a:number):void
}

class C implements A, B {
    foo: (a:string | number) => void;
    constructor() {
        this.foo = (a:string | number) => {}
    }
}
```

Comment: По разному методы назвать нельзя. Сделал перегрузку.